# 4 columns in desktop, 2 in tablet and 1 in mobile using bootstrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Its very interesting and helpful to use Bootstrap, currently i am facing problem during creating following requirement.

"4 columns in desktop, 2 columns in tablet and 1 column in mobile using bootstrap"
can anybody tell me the correct structure

Comment: Create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: This is even given as an example in their documentation!

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed-complete

Comment: ya i've tried that but its not working with tablet mode, i have used http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/ example and i have made those 3 divs to 4 (which are having circular shaped image) and made its class col-md-6. currently i am having 4 boxes like those 3 boxes

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not sure this is what you want, but look at this :-

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FbXzM/)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">Col 1</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">Col 2</div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">Col 3</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">Col 4</div>
</div>
```

--- [UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FbXzM/2/) ---

Comment: hey should i need to add <div class="clearfix visible-md"></div> after second one, because third and forth are not properly working

Comment: see i am having one image and content in each div, after 2nd div 3rd, fourth are not properly aligned. Thats the issue.

Comment: ok...on which device it is not properly aligned(desktop, tablet or mobile)?

Comment: check the UPDATED DEMO.

Comment: not yet, i am checking whether any other things is going wrong

Comment: its done, this is my structure http://jsfiddle.net/FbXzM/6/. but its working in fiddle but not on browser

Comment: Yup..enjoy coding ahead.. :)

Comment: it is solved, i have applied style="width:140px;height:140px;" to image and it is working in all modes! thanks

Comment: I think `<div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div>` this is what made it work.

Comment: How would you get column 2 and column 4 to come to the left side of the window stacked on top of each other - like they are before the collapse? - instead of going in between the other divs? So that content on the right is separated from the content in the left - vertically - after collapse...:)