# 4 columns in Desktop 2 column in Mobile view bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking for a solution where in desktop 4 column and in Mobile it will be 2 columns

I tried this solution from [STO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21231070/4-columns-in-desktop-2-in-tablet-and-1-in-mobile-using-bootstrap) It didn't worked for me.

I am using bootstrap 5 version.

Here is my code

```
<div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
                            <h3 class="news_let">
                                Resources
                            </h3>
                            <ul class="ft_conte">
                                <li>
                                    Desktop Client
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    Mobile apps
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    Form Center
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    Margin File
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    Margin Calculator
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    Brokerage Calculator
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
                            <h3 class="news_let">
                                About the Company
                            </h3>
                            <ul class="ft_conte">
                                <li>
                                    About Us
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    Blog
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    Privacy policy
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    Term of Use
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    Complaint Book
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    Contact Us
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
                            <h3 class="news_let">
                                Careers
                            </h3>
                            <ul class="ft_conte">
                                <li>
                                    About Us
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    Blog
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    Privacy policy
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    Term of Use
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    Complaint Book
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    Contact Us
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
                            <h3 class="news_let">
                                Legal
                            </h3>
                            <ul class="ft_conte">
                                <li>
                                    Investor
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    Privacy policy
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    Risk & Compliance
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    Policy
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    Disclaimer
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    Filling of Complaints<br/> On SCORES
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

in desktop mode it is coming correct but in mobile mode it is not coming in two section

Here is the version I am using Please let me know what I am doing wrong here

[bootstrap](http://%3Clink%20href=%22https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css%22%20rel=%22stylesheet%22%20integrity=%22sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC%22%20crossorigin=%22anonymous%22%3E)

In Mobile View

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap has removed all `@-xs-*` classes in version **4+**. So there isn't any `col-xs-*` classes. Use `col-6` and `col-sm-3`.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-6">
    <h3 class="news_let">
      Resources
    </h3>
    <ul class="ft_conte">
      <li>
        Desktop Client
      </li>
      <li>
        Mobile apps
      </li>
      <li>
        Form Center
      </li>
      <li>
        Margin File
      </li>
      <li>
        Margin Calculator
      </li>
      <li>
        Brokerage Calculator
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-6">
    <h3 class="news_let">
      About the Company
    </h3>
    <ul class="ft_conte">
      <li>
        About Us
      </li>
      <li>
        Blog
      </li>
      <li>
        Privacy policy
      </li>
      <li>
        Term of Use
      </li>
      <li>
        Complaint Book
      </li>
      <li>
        Contact Us
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-6">
    <h3 class="news_let">
      Careers
    </h3>
    <ul class="ft_conte">
      <li>
        About Us
      </li>
      <li>
        Blog
      </li>
      <li>
        Privacy policy
      </li>
      <li>
        Term of Use
      </li>
      <li>
        Complaint Book
      </li>
      <li>
        Contact Us
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-6">
    <h3 class="news_let">
      Legal
    </h3>
    <ul class="ft_conte">
      <li>
        Investor
      </li>
      <li>
        Privacy policy
      </li>
      <li>
        Risk & Compliance
      </li>
      <li>
        Policy
      </li>
      <li>
        Disclaimer
      </li>
      <li>https://srv.buysellads.com/ads/click/x/GTND42JIC6BIC23MC6SLYKQNCKYI42QMCT7IKZ3JCY7I4KQUFTYI62JKCYSD42QJCEBI523NCEYDK2QUF6BDKK3KC6SDCKQMCKADTK3EHJNCLSIZ Filling of Complaints<br/> On SCORES
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You did it right, but a class is missing. add "col-sm-6" to all